# Schema.org for Industrial Design product Portfolio

Tags: schema, schema.org

Problem: Industrial Design portfolio build.

Business/Organisation Offers a ProfessionalService

ie: https://schema.org/ProfessionalService

They have a Portfolio, with Medical devices, Industrial devices, and Consumer Electronics. NONE of which are "products for sale" on their site.

Question:
**Whats the correct SCHEMA for each portfolio item?**

For example:
|
schema.org/CreativeWork
|VS|
health-lifesci.schema.org/MedicalDevice

Ive even checked http://health-lifesci.0.3-2e.schemaorgae.appspot.com/ 
for "more specific types"...

At this time, i've settled on using CreativeWork, seems legit. Any thoughts on the proper classification for an Industrial Design portfolio? Should I submit this to Schema.org?

Thanks for your consideration...

Comment: So you want to represent the physical objects, right? What properties do you want to provide for these?

Comment: ProfessionalService from Organisation offers CreativeWork 
Specifically, "industrial design of medical products"
Therefore, which schema applies to the "product portfolio" items. Lets say there is a surgical Stint, on a WebPage called website.com/portfolio/stint.html as such, the containing div should be what? CreativeWork? MedicalDevice? ect... (maybe I am overthinking this)